# Php code in laravel blade php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I m trying to add `<?php echo $_GET["tname"] ?>` in my laravel login form to use it as this `https://example.com/?tname=test` to get it auto-filled value, but when ever i try to add it it says

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Can anyone tell me how to use that code in it.
Here's my laravel login page code:

```
<form class="" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
    <div class="panel panel-body">
        <h4 class="text-semibold mt-0">{{ trans('messages.login') }}</h4>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="{{ trans("messages.email") }}"
                 value="<?php echo $_GET["tname"]; ?>"
            >
```

Comment: Please, use blade functions in a blade template.

Comment: can u tell exact function name?

Comment: To output data use `{{ $variable }}`, value of a variable set in a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<?php echo $_GET["tname"]; ?>
```

just use:

```
{{ request()->input('tname') }}
```

You should not use PHP code in Blade even you can use `@php ... @endphp` directives

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP code block explicitly, you can use it within blade tags `@php` /*some regular PHP code*/ `@endphp` and in your case it could be:

```
<form class="" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
    <div class="panel panel-body">
        <h4 class="text-semibold mt-0">{{ trans('messages.login') }}</h4>

        @php
            $a = 5;
            $b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
            $c = isset($_GET['tname']) ? $_GET['tname'] : null;
        @endphp
        <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="{{ trans("messages.email") }}"
             value="{{ $c }}">
```

Of course, using GET variable without PHP input sanitation wouldn't be much smart and that's why @MarcinNabiałek and @AlexeyMazenin answers are correct. I am here just pointing of how would you use PHP block code in blade regarding question title.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-request) helper to get URI parameter:

```
value="{{ request('tname') }}"
```